# Service wouldn't stop if it has another service bound to it

Tags: android, android-service

I have an `Activity` (let's say A) and two `Service`s (S1 and S2). And here how it goes:

1. A starts S1 with `startService()`
2. S1 binds to S2 (in `onCreate()` using `bindService()`)
3. A stops S1 (with `stopService()`)
4. Both S1 and S2 are still started. Why?

I read that in above situation S1 would wait for all the services bound to it (like S2) to unbind. But I want to stop S2 in S1's `onDestroy()` (`A.stopService(S1)` -> `S1.onDestroy(){ unbind(S2) }`). How could I do that?